# Simple Advice where to save setting

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, settings

Im programming C# WinForm application which have big SQL Server Database.
I need to make setting.
I dont know how to save application setting. Which is better just add my solution .setting file or save in database Table?

Comment: should your winform application be able to also work detached from the DB (e.g. on a laptop while you're travelling)? Are your application settings customizable by user? If so, do your users authenticate to use the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to say it, but it depends on whether the setting is intended to span all clients to the database, vs whether different nodes/applications would require different values. Having the values in the database can make it easier to centrally configure the system via the system itself (an admin page), without needing to re-deploy or reconfigure any nodes.

Disconnected clients can also work either way, as long as they capture the settings locally when connected (being able to connect at least once is not unreasonable).

Of course, even per-node settings can be in the db if you add suitable dimensions to the table. The one setting that is a pain, of course, being the connection details...

Answer (score 3):

use application configuration file to save your app wise settings.

Answer (score 2):

Depend of your needs, when use app.settings (tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx ) file it will be stored with application itself, when you strore them in database is more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You **edit: (*have*) (sure you don't have, sorry for my poor english ....) you *can*** to store configuration in the app.config file. [Here's](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3396111/Using-Application-Configuration-Files-in-NET.htm) a post about using configurations files.
Informations will be accessible by the Configuration manager ([Msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)) Class.